# CDN CNAMEs not resolving to customer origin

Tags: dns, cdn

I have set up an Edgecast CDN to mirror all my static content.  Because I use the root of my domain (`donaldjenkins.com`) to host my main site—using Google Analytics which sets cookies—I've stored the corresponding static files in a separate [cookieless](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/request.html#ServeFromCookielessDomain) domain (`donaldjenkins.info`) which is used only for this purpose.  I've set it up (using this [(mt) guide](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1849/Getting+started+with+ProCDN#procdn) for general guidance), with the following structure, based on a combination of customer origin and CDN origin to make the most of the chosen short domain name and provide meaningful URLs:

1. `http://donaldjenkins.info:80` is set as the **customer origin** for the content stored in the CDN at directory `http://wac.62E0.edgecastcdn.net/8062E0/donaldjenkins.info`;
2. I've then set up various subdomains of a separate domain, the conveniently-named `cdn.dj`, as **CDN-origin** Edge CNAMEs for each of the corresponding static content types:

   - `js.cdn.dj` points to the origin directory `http://wac.62E0.edgecastcdn.net/0062E0/donaldjenkins.info/js`;
   - `css.cdn.dj` points to the origin directory `http://wac.62E0.edgecastcdn.net/0062E0/donaldjenkins.info/css`;
   - `images.cdn.dj` points to the origin directory `http://wac.62E0.edgecastcdn.net/0062E0/donaldjenkins.info/images`

and so on.  This results in some pretty nice, short, clear URLs.

The DNS zone file for `cdn.dj` (yes, it's a real domain name registered in Djibouti) is set properly:

```
cdn.dj          43200   IN   A       205.186.157.162     
css.cdn.dj      43200   IN   CNAME   wac.62E0.edgecastcdn.net.
images.cdn.dj   43200   IN   CNAME   wac.62E0.edgecastcdn.net.
js.cdn.dj       43200   IN   CNAME   wac.62E0.edgecastcdn.net.
```

The DNS resolves to the Edgecast URL:

```
$ host js.cdn.dj
js.cdn.dj is an alias for wac.62E0.edgecastcdn.net.
wac.62E0.edgecastcdn.net is an alias for gs1.wac.edgecastcdn.net.
gs1.wac.edgecastcdn.net has address 93.184.220.20
```

But whenever I try to fetch a file in any of the directories to which the CNAME assets map, I get a 404:

```
$ curl http://js.cdn.dj/combined.js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>404 - Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

despite the fact that the corresponding customer origin file exists:

```
$ curl http://donaldjenkins.info/js/combined.js
```

fetches the content of the `combined.js` file. Yet it's been more than enough time for the DNS to propagate since I set up the CDN.

There's obviously some glaring mistake in the above-described setup, and I'm a bit of a novice with CDNs—but any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: I have the same issue - were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Two things I can see here.

1. You're mapping `js.cdn.dj` to `wac.edgecastcdn.net`. This looks correct so far. When you're curling, you're using `js.cdn.dj/combined.js` but when you use the full `http://donaldjenkins.info/js/combined.js` (which works) you're adding a subdirectory. Did you try `js.cdn.dj/js/combined.js` ?
2. CDNs can be a bit tricky in that even if your DNS is correct, they have to have all the right mappings right on their side. There is probably a configuration xml or domain mapping setting on whatever UI you have with then that you should check to verify that even though the DNS resolves, their web servers have the alternate domains as aliases so they actually connect up.